# Calculating $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k^{-8}$ using Parseval´s identity

Tags: fourier-series, parsevals-identity

I calculated the Fourier series of $x^2$ getting

$$x^2=\frac{\pi^2}{3}+4\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} \cos(kx)$$

Then, integrating this equation two times i got

$$\frac{x^4-2\pi^2x^2}{12}=4\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^4} \cos(kx)$$

Using the Parseval's identity $\sum c_k^2=\int f^2$ i obtained that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^8}=\frac{107}{362880}\pi^8 $$

which, according to Wolfram Alpha should be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1} {k^8}=\frac{\pi^8} {9450}$

I can't find where my error is. Is my proceeding wrong or am I just missing something?

Comment: When you integrated twice, did you take care of the constants of integration? In your second equation, after integrating, the left-hand side is zero at $x=0$, while the right-hand side is not.

Comment: I didn't consider the constants of integration. If you do you get c=0 from the first integral and $c=4\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^4} $ from the second integral. Not really sure how to go after that. Maybe i should do the fourier series of $x^4$ and apply Parseval to that, although that would require some lengthy integrals.

Comment: The missing integration constants are what is explaining your error. Finding them is equivalent to solving the original question in the first place. As you said, it's better to directly compute the Fourier expansion of $x^4$ and then apply Parseval.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with
$$ \frac{\theta^2}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{12} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \, \cos(n \theta) $$
then, by integration, the series
$$ \frac{\theta^3}{12} - \frac{\zeta(2) \, \theta}{2} + c_{1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3} \, \sin(n \theta) $$
is obtained. The constant of integration, $c_{1}$ is found to be zero by evaluating the series at $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$. Now integrating once again the resulting series is
$$ \frac{\theta^4}{48} - \frac{\zeta(2) \, \theta^2}{4} + c_{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4} \, \cos(n \theta). $$
Evaluating this series at $\theta = 0$, or $\theta = \pi$, the constant $c_{2}$ can be found and leads to the series
$$ \frac{\theta^4}{48} - \frac{\zeta(2) \, \theta^2}{4} + \frac{7 \, \zeta(4)}{8} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4} \, \cos(n \theta). $$

Now, by Pasreval's theorem for Fourier Series, it can be seen that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4} \right)^2 &= \frac{1}{\pi} \, \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( \frac{\theta^4}{48} - \frac{\zeta(2) \, \theta^2}{4} + \frac{7 \, \zeta(4)}{8} \right)^2 \, d\theta \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^8} &= \frac{2}{\pi} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( \frac{\theta^4}{48} - \frac{\zeta(2) \, \theta^2}{4} + \frac{7 \, \zeta(4)}{8} \right)^2 \, d\theta \\
\zeta(8) &= \frac{2}{\pi} \, \left[ \frac{\theta^9}{20736} - \frac{\zeta(2) \, \theta^7}{672} + \frac{37 \, \zeta^{2}(2) \, \theta^5}{2400} - \frac{7 \, \zeta^{3}(2) \, \theta^3}{120} + \frac{49 \, \zeta^{4}(2) \, \theta}{400} \right]_{0}^{\pi} \\
&= \frac{\pi^8}{9450}.
\end{align}
Comparing this result to that from [MathWorld Zeta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) then it is determined that
$$ \zeta(8) = \frac{\pi^8}{9450} $$
is the correct result.